# Advantage of platform dependent integer sizes

Tags: go, integer

The size of Go's `int` datatype is platform dependent but a minimum of 32 bits, according to the [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#int).

What's the advantage of having a native datatype which size is platform dependent (considering the uncertainty it introduces)?

Is the native type just faster or are there more advantages?

Comment: Also see related / possible duplicate: [What is the implication of using a specific numeric type over another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52076575/what-is-the-implication-of-using-a-specific-numeric-type-over-another/52077161#52077161)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What's the advantage of having a datatype which size is platform dependent [...]?

It is the native (i.e. hardware defined) type of the platform. The underlying hardware has a certain bit width of its integer types (modern hardwares are 64 or 32 bits). It is sensible to have native == hardware types for a language which provides and allows low level optimisations.

Comment: I am aware of that and it doesn't answer my question. My Question was: What is the advantage of using a native type?

Comment: @Cookie04 Native types are platform native that is the advantage. (Read faster and more natural). (And no, you did ask about "platform dependent" types not native types.)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on "platform dependent" vs "native", but why don't you just write that in your answer then? Also could you elaborate on the meaning of "natural" ? What does that mean exactly?

Comment: Thanks for the improvements to your answer, but could you further elaborate on the reason the bit width of the integer type and the cpu architecture should match up? Is it just speed?

Comment: @Cookie04 I'm not sure I understand this request. Your hardware has a natural size of its integers (and often floating points) types. Integer types include pointer types which are used to address memory. It is so absolute clear and obvious that the hardware defined natural bit with of integers is sensible that I do not know how to describe it. The only sensible question would be why it was called `int` and not `intNat` or `archInt` ore something like that.

Comment: Working with int64 on 32bit systems must be done via software as the hardware cannot handle 64bits en bloc. So yes, it is all about speed. Artificially limiting 64bit hardware to 32 bits is just crazy for most tasks. Just think how a []int would look like in memory if int was 32bit in 64 hardware. That's just insane.

Comment: Okay thanks. That's all I wanted to know, so the answer would be: "No, there is no other advantage than speed"