# Memory layout of arrays in Go?

Tags: go, memory, low-level

My code is below. When I check the address of the values it is stored as `280 288 290 298`. Why is it stored in this pattern?

```
package main
    
import "fmt"

func main() {
    const a = 1111111111111111111
    test := [7]int{a, 1, 33333,4,6,7,7}

    fmt.Println(&test[0])
    fmt.Println(&test[1])
    fmt.Println(&test[2])
    fmt.Println(&test[3])
    fmt.Println(&test[4])
    fmt.Println(&test[5])
    fmt.Println(&test[6])
}
```

output :

```
0xc00000e280
0xc00000e288
0xc00000e290
0xc00000e298
0xc00000e2a0
0xc00000e2a8
0xc00000e2b0
```

Comment: The addresses are in hex, so the "pattern" is just contiguous 8-byte addresses.  `8+8 == 0x10`

Comment: I missed this basic part thnx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unsurprisingly, Go arrays are laid out contiguously in memory. Then since Go types are [statically sized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67839752/why-does-an-empty-slice-have-24-bytes/67839917#67839917), the address of the nth item is equal to the address of the 0th element plus a byte offset equal to the size of the type of the item.

This can be roughly formalized as (pseudo code):

```
addr_n = addr_0 + (n * size_of(item))
```

And in Go code, using [`unsafe.Add`](https://pkg.go.dev/unsafe#Add) (since Go 1.17):

```
func main() {
    const a = 1111111111111111111
    x := [7]int{a, 1, 33333, 4, 6, 7, 7}

    unsafePointer := unsafe.Pointer(&x[0])
    for i := range x {
        step := unsafe.Sizeof(int(0))
        addr_n := unsafe.Add(unsafePointer, int(step)*i)
        fmt.Printf("addr: %p, val: %d\n", addr_n, *(*int)(addr_n))
    }
}
```

Which prints:

```
addr: 0xc000102000, val: 1111111111111111111
addr: 0xc000102008, val: 1
addr: 0xc000102010, val: 33333
addr: 0xc000102018, val: 4
addr: 0xc000102020, val: 6
addr: 0xc000102028, val: 7
addr: 0xc000102030, val: 7
```

<sup>In case it wasn't already crystal clear, the hex number is the memory address. This is how pointers are usually formatted by the `fmt` package.</sup>

However note that the size of `int` in particular is [platform-dependent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52076575/what-is-the-implication-of-using-a-specific-numeric-type-over-another/52077161#52077161), hence in the snippet above you can't just add `8`. To make it deterministic, you can use `unsafe.Sizeof(int(0))`.

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/4hu8efVed96